# Postgresql: Cannot restore schema from pg_dump

Tags: database, postgresql, database-backups

I am trying to move a schema from one database to another using `pg_dump`.
I am running this command to take a backup of my schema

```
pg_dump.exe -h myhost -U postgres -d mydb-n schema> C:\Temp\schema.dump
```

To restore it I copy the `SQL` into `pgadmin`, but I get this error. I don't know what the issue is ?

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 284: 2 \N  Unregistered. Item  \N  2016-07-13 00:00:00 \N
```

Is there a best recommended way to backup/restore a `postgres` database? I often run into issues similar issues when backing up/restoring databases and I start to worry that I will loose valuable data one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plain text `pg_dump` cannot be restored with pgAdmin since pgAdmin cannot perform `COPY FROM STDIN`, which is used by `pg_dump` for the data by default.

You'll have to use `psql` to restore the dump.

An alternative would be to use the `--inserts` option of `pg_dump` so that the data are dumped as `INSERT` statrments. This comes with a performance penalty though.

Comment: Just to clearify, with pgAdmin, do you mean that you cannot use the restore function? I meant copy the plain text sql into a querry tool to run it as any other SQL queries.

Comment: Right, that's what you cannot do with pgAdmin.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was not using the restore function, just copy/paste and run on the plain text sql. Perhaps the error is something to do with indexes. Thought plain text would be a safer option, but seems like I have to rethink my strategy. I simply just want to copy my schema and data from my dev db to my production db, retaining, pk,fk and triggers and serial values.

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry confused myself for a second. psql ran it succesfully